# Removing objects from array with the click of a button React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to be able to remove the products I store in an array state (hook) with the click of a button that is on the cart element. But everytime I click my button it deletes the entirety of the items stored in the array.

Here's my code:

```
 export const CartContext = createContext([]);
    
    export function CartProvider({ children }) {
        
        
        const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
        const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
    
    
        //Adding items.
    
        const addItem = (product, quantity, id) => {
            if(quantity === 1){
                alert("Product added to carrr")
        } else {
            alert("Products added to cart")
        };
            setProducts([...products, {...product, quantity : quantity, id:id}]);
            
        console.log("Producto: ", product);
        setTotal(products.length + 1)
        };
    
    
        // const totalCart = ({products, quantity}) =>{
        //     setTotal (products.map(product => product.price).reduce((prev, next)=> prev + next)*quantity);
        //     console.log ("El totalCart: ", total);
        // }

//Avoiding duplicates
        const isInCart = (id) => {
            const existe = products.find((e) => e.id === id);
            console.log("Existe", existe)
            return existe;
            
    
          };
        //Clearing the cart
    
        const clearCart=()=>{
                setProducts([]);
                console.log("Carro vacío");
                alert("El carro está vacío")
                setTotal(0);
        }
        //Removing items one by one 
         const removeItem = (id) => {
            
            const deleted = products.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
            setProducts(deleted);
            setTotal(products.length - 1);
           
            
             alert("Se quitó un producto")
           };
    
    

    
    

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ products, addItem, total, clearCart, isInCart, removeItem }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );

}
```

Then I send the context to the cart, which by the way warns me that I should have a key for every item on a list but doesn't seem to notice that I am trying to define the key

```
const Cart = () =>{

const { products, total, clearCart, removeItem} = useContext(CartContext);

console.log("Products in cart: ", products);
console.log ("Total of items: ", total   );


return(

<div>

    <h1>Productos en el carro: {products.length}</h1>
    <div>
    {products.map((product) => {
            return (
              <Fragment >
               <div key={product.id}>
                
                  <p>cantidad agregada: {product.quantity}</p>
                
                  <button onClick={()=>removeItem(product.id)}>Quitar</button>
                  </div>
               
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
    </div>
    <button onClick={clearCart}>Limpiar carro</button>
</div>    
    
)
```

}

export default Cart

Comment: its bit of confused using state hook in context provider. "This is why state is often called local or encapsulated. It is not accessible to any component other than the one that owns and sets it." - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
i recommend to try useReducer hook to do your job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the context just to share the `state` and the `setState` functions.

```
 export const CartContext = createContext([]);
    
    export function CartProvider({ children }) {
        
        
        const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
        const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
  

    return (
        <CartContext.Provider value={{ products, setProducts, setTotal, total }}>
            {children}
        </CartContext.Provider>
    );

}
```

You can now have your functions inside the children or create a new `component`, so you can access them from anywhere.

```
const Cart = () =>{

const { products, total } = useContext(CartContext);

console.log("Products in cart: ", products);
console.log ("Total of items: ", total   );

        //Adding items.
    
        const addItem = (product, quantity, id) => {
            if(quantity === 1){
                alert("Product added to carrr")
        } else {
            alert("Products added to cart")
        };
            setProducts([...products, {...product, quantity : quantity, id:id}]);
            
        console.log("Producto: ", product);
        setTotal(products.length + 1)
        };
    
    
        // const totalCart = ({products, quantity}) =>{
        //     setTotal (products.map(product => product.price).reduce((prev, next)=> prev + next)*quantity);
        //     console.log ("El totalCart: ", total);
        // }

//Avoiding duplicates
        const isInCart = (id) => {
            const existe = products.find((e) => e.id === id);
            console.log("Existe", existe)
            return existe;
            
    
          };

 const clearCart=()=>{
                setProducts([]);
                console.log("Carro vacío");
                alert("El carro está vacío")
                setTotal(0);
        }
        //Removing items one by one 
         const removeItem = (id) => {
            
            const deleted = products.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
            setProducts(deleted);
            setTotal(products.length - 1);
           
            
             alert("Se quitó un producto")
           };

return(

<div>

    <h1>Productos en el carro: {products.length}</h1>
    <div>
    {products.map((product) => {
            return (
              <Fragment >
               <div key={product.id}>
                
                  <p>cantidad agregada: {product.quantity}</p>
                
                  <button onClick={()=>removeItem(product.id)}>Quitar</button>
                  </div>
               
              </Fragment>
            );
          })}
    </div>
    <button onClick={clearCart}>Limpiar carro</button>
</div>    
    
)
}

export default Cart
```